# CodeIgniter: how to pass values from a specific function to another one

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to pass a value coming from a form using the method post from a function to another one.

```
class Send_value extends CI_Controller {

public function main_page() {
     $data['user'] = $this->input->post('fullName');
      ...
}


public function welcome_page(){
  //Now I would like to pass $data['user'] here.      

}
}
```

How can I pass it in the second function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass parameter within that function and need to define that parameter as

```
class Send_value extends CI_Controller {

public function main_page() {
     $data['user'] = $this->input->post('fullName');
     echo $data['user']; //echoing value from post
     if(!empty($data)){
        $this->welcome_page($data); //passing data into another function
     } else {
        echo "Didn't get value from post";
     }
}


public function welcome_page($data = ''){
                           //^^ parameter set within function
    if(is_array($data) && count($data) > 0){
       print_r($data);
    } else {
       echo "No result found";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I passed the parameter as explained above, but print_r($data) returns an empty value.

Comment: I have updated my code are you getting value within `$data['user']` try to print_r or echo it first

Comment: Hi, I get  'No result found'

Comment: Yep its because you're not gettiing value within `$data` check are you getting value within `function main_page()`

Comment: Hi Narendra, I did not quite understand what you exactly mean.The value comes from main_page()

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your other method accept a parameter and then you can pass $data to it.

```
class Send_value extends CI_Controller {

public function main_page() {
     $data['user'] = $this->input->post('fullName');
    $this -> welcome_page($data);
}


public function welcome_page($data){
  //Now I would like to pass $data['user'] here.      
    echo $data['user'];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function main_page() {
     $data['user'] = $this->input->post('fullName');
     $this->welcome_page($data['user']);
     ...
}


public function welcome_page($zz){
  //Now I would like to pass $data['user'] here.
  //$zz contains your post data

}
```