# Pass values between functions in the same controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to pass a specific value from one function to another, in the same controller.

```
class Send_email extends CI_Controller {
    public function main_page() { 
        $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
        $this->call_back_email($data);
    }
    public function call_back_email($data){
        echo $data['email'];
    }
}
```

I get the same result if I change the script, as shown below:

```
class Send_email extends CI_Controller {
    public function main_page() { 
        $data['email'] = 'myemail@test.com';
        $this->call_back_email($data);
    }
    public function call_back_email($data){
        echo $data['email'];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the script above does not work. How can I exactly pass it to the `call_back_email()` function?

Comment: It might be because you were not getting value within your post. I have answered the question [codeigniter-how-to-pass-values-from-a-specific-function-to-another-one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612324/codeigniter-how-to-pass-values-from-a-specific-function-to-another-one/29612450#29612450) you can check it there

Comment: Hi, I read your answer. I am getting the value from the method post. If I change $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email'); into $data['email'] = 'myemail@tes.it'; I obtain the same result.

Comment: First point is you dont need to. If there is a value present in `$this->input->post()` in your `main_page()` function you can just call it out of there in your `call_back_email()` function. No need to assign it to a new variable

Comment: Your second code block is correct and should work. Are you visiting main_page in your browser? If so is it echo'ing anything at all? If not you probably have a suppressed error or something

Comment: Try **public function __construct() { parent::__construct(); error_reporting(E_ALL); }** and check if any error exist

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the support. I passed the value as suggested by Mike ans the script works as expected.